# Show number of views in the last 48 hours

Tags: views

I have now the most popular views on the posts I have. But I want to show the most viewed in the last 48 hours. How can I achieve that?

Someone helped me and I placed this in single.php file.

$post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post_view_count = get_post_meta($post_id, 'view_count', true);

```
    if( $post_view_count=='' ) {                
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'view_count', 1);                
    }
    else{
            $post_view_count = intval($post_view_count);
            ++$post_view_count;
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'view_count', $post_view_count);
    }
```

And I have this in tabs4.php to show the 4 tabs on my website:

```
$args_popular = array (
            'posts_per_page'         => '5',
            'order'                  => 'DESC',
            'orderby'                => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key'               => 'view_count',
            'day'                    => '2',
            'cache_results'          => true,
```

But current day => 2 is not working.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to identify when each of the page view's recorded happened.  It's only logging the page view, not when it happened.

To work around this you could keep a post_meta entry for each view, but this could create a lot of entries on popular sites.  Alternatively you could keep daily counts & delete any that were over 2 days old (if you're only interested in 48 hours), as well as maintaining the running total count.

Here's a suggested solution for the daily count method...

To add the daily counts...

```
$post_id               = get_the_ID();
$post_view_count       = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'view_count', true );
$post_daily_view_count = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'view_daily_counts', true );
$post_recent_count     = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'view_recent_count', true );

if ( $post_view_count == '' ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'view_count', 1 );
} else {
    $post_view_count = intval( $post_view_count );
    ++$post_view_count;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'view_count', $post_view_count );
}

$today             = new DateTime;
$days_to_consider  = 2; // How many days to consider when looking for recent views?
$delete_befre_date = new DateTime( "-{$days_to_consider} days" );

// Create the meta entry if doesn't already exist
if ( $post_daily_view_count == '' ) {
    $post_daily_view_count = array( $today->format( 'Y-m-d' ) => 1 );

// Otherwise, update the existing one
} else { // if ( $post_daily_view_count == '' )

    // Update the entry for today
    $post_daily_view_count[$today->format( 'Y-m-d' )] = intval( $post_daily_view_count[$today->format( 'Y-m-d' )] );
    ++$post_daily_view_count[$today->format( 'Y-m-d' )];

} // if ( $post_daily_view_count == '' )

// Calculate the recent total, removing entries older than X days from the recent counts
$recent_count = 0;
foreach ( array_keys( $post_daily_view_count ) as $date ) {
    if ( $date < $delete_befre_date->format( 'Y-m-d' ) ) {
        unset( $post_daily_view_count[$date] );
    } else {
        $recent_count = $recent_count + $post_daily_view_count[$date];
    }
}

// And save the update meta
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'view_daily_counts', $post_daily_view_count );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'view_recent_count', $recent_count );
```

Then to query the posts...

```
$args_popular = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'view_recent_count',
    'cache_results'  => true,
);
```

To change the number of days kept, change the value of `$days_to_consider` in the first block of code.

Comment: Wow man. What an answer. The code looks scary to me ;) So if I want only 2 days I put this?

$delete_befre_date = new DateTime( "-2 days" ); 

Is that right?

Comment: If you look t the line above that, you can set $days_to_consider = {the number of days you want};

Comment: Thank you Toby. I have the initial code added in Single.php do I replace the new code with it? or I have to add it in another file?

Comment: This should replace what was there before.  Note if you had a previous count, this will not take that into consideration & only start counting from now.  Also note that I've reformatted the code above as the top lines were not showing as code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it. But there is a small problem: The posts are always changing. No idea why. And the number of posts if now 6 instead of 5 even in tabs4.php I have posts => 5. Can I upload my files here please and you can have a look?

Website: http://www.f1zone.net/news/williams-reveals-pre-launch-image-of-fw36/21761/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could add them to pastebin or create a gist on http://gist.github.com/ & I'll try to take a look, or someone else might.